# angular routerLink redirects to component as expected, but later router.url not returning current URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a link in my navbar `About` when I click on it from my homepage (`/`), browser redirects to `/about` route(`About` component) in my application(without reloading the page/tab) which is what I am looking for.

In the component `About` I have a requirement where I need to load the content dynamically depending on the Url that I am on. I tried many ways of getting the current Url but it always returns "/" or does not return anything at all. What I have and what I believe should work without any problem follows below:

**Link on the navbar**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/about/who-i-am']" class="media d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="icon icon-shape bg-gradient-primary rounded-circle text-white">
                  <i class="ni ni-palette"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body ml-3">
                  <h6 class="heading text-primary mb-md-1">Who I am</h6>
                  <p class="description d-none d-md-inline-block mb-0">Small 2 line text goes in here about yourself and your blog/articles.</p>
                </div>
              </a>
```

**`About` Component `ts` file**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar-hero-content-section',
  templateUrl: './navbar-hero-content-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar-hero-content-section.component.css']
})
export class NavbarHeroContentSectionComponent implements OnInit {

  isWhoIam : Boolean = false;
  isHome : Boolean = false;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    var currentUrl: string;

    // Current Path:  company 
    // this.route.url.subscribe(url => {
    //   currentUrl = url[0].path;
    // });


    currentUrl = this.router.url;//the problem is here with currentUrl always returning "/" or the URL I came to this component/page from.

    console.log("current URL : " + currentUrl); 



    switch(currentUrl)
    {
      case "/" : 
      case "/home" :
      {
        this.isHome = true;
      }

      case "/about/who-i-am" : {
        this.isWhoIam = true;
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Any idea what could be happening here, I tried different ways to get the currentUrl with using `Location/document` and even `window`, all of them seem to be returning the same `/`

**UPDATE**:

Now I realized that the code in the `ngOnInit()` does not even execute/run when I click the link. **I added a Date.now() to the `console.log` and when I click back and forth between the '/about/who-i-am' and '/' I see that the console log displays the same timestamp in the browser, it does not even change.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be by using

```
this.location.path()
```

or in your case something like

```
this.location.path().inlcudes('home')
```

Location has to be imported

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

and added to the constructor

```
private location: Location,
```

Update - try adding this to ngOnInit:

```
 this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       // evt.url should update when the url gets updated
       // and you can use it whereever needed
      }
    });
```

Comment: When I use Location, per your suggestion, It still loads "/" as the current URL, but after I navigate to the component, I manually reload the page, then it shows I am on "/about/who-i-am". I dont want the page reload, things work well with 'href' but reloads the page, which slows down the load.

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your updated answer with `router.events` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window** to get URL something like that

> let currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
>
> console.log('current URL :', currentUrl);

Have a good code!